# vb.net, Windows Mobile, Bluetooth Portable Printer. How to print image?

Tags: vb.net, printing, bluetooth, serial-port, windows-mobile

I have a windows mobile device with a bluetooth portable receipt printer, I need to print a .PNG image on the receipt but i cant find the way to do this. 
Here's the code that's concerned with the printer.

```
    Dim p As System.IO.Ports.SerialPort

    Dim Port As String = "COM8" 
    p = New System.IO.Ports.SerialPort(Port)
    p.WriteTimeout = 5000
    p.ReadTimeout = 5000
    p.BaudRate = 9600

    Try
        If Not p.IsOpen Then p.Open()
        'p.WriteLine(textToPrint)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)

    Finally
        If p.IsOpen Then p.Close()
        p.Dispose()
    End Try
```

I have two options:

So p.WriteLine() just writes a regular String

But p.Write() has 3 overloads:

- 1st overload: p.Write(text as String)
- 2nd overload: p.Write(buffer() as Char, offset as integer, count as integer)
- 3rd overload: p.Write(buffer() as Byte, offset as integer, count as integer)

I have no idea to do print the Image, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Any we have no idea either. You need to programmers reference manual for the printer if you are going to connect using a serial port

Comment: isn't there a way to like convert the image to char array or bytes or something and print that result ? or am i way of on this?

Comment: Yes there is but you need to know what format the printer is expecting the data in. They are all different.

Comment: What is th printer's model code and which printer cmd langauge does it use? Possibly it is using ESC/P, ZPL, FingePrint or any other printer cmd language. First you need to convert the image to b&w and then send the printers bitmap command and then the data using a byte buffer.

Comment: ok so i downloaded the printer's DLL and i got it set up, and it has these functions for printing: 

Write() and WriteFile() 

but the problem is i tried both of them, passed the image the the WriteFile() but it still printed a lot of random letters but no image, and i also tried sending the output buffer of the saved bmp image to the Write() but also same problem. 

am i missing on something? is there a special format for the image object? I couldn't find any code related to this on the internet.. maybe i'm not searching enough... back to searching... 

Oh and the printer is a Intermec-PB3